# Line of greatest slope

Tags: 3d

Assuming the plane $4x-3y+7z=0$ to be horizontal, find the equation of the line of greatest slope through the point $(2,1,1)$ in the plane $2x+y-5z=0$

Comment: I think there should be a line which passes through the intersection of two given planes.

Comment: Define horizontal

Comment: Horizontal means we have taken the given plane as reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a good idea to determine first the intersection of the two planes. So let us solve:

$$4x-3y+7z=0$$ 
$$2x+y-5z=0$$

Eliminating $x$ yields $5y = 17z$. Substituting this result back in either of the two equations, we obtain the following result for the straight line which is the intersection of the two planes:

$$(x,y,z) = C * (4,17,5)$$

We observe that this line defines the direction in the second plane with minimal slope (namely horizontal = zero slope) to the first plane. Therefore we must find the vector that is orthogonal to this line. This vector must also be orthogonal to the normal of the second plane. Hence the vector must satisfy these two equations:

$$4x+17y+5z=0$$
$$2x+y-5z=0$$

Eliminating $x$ tields $y = -z$. Substituting this back into our equations yields the vector $(3,-1,1)$. Therefore the line through $(2,1,1)$ with the greatest slope is given by:

$$(x,y,z) = (2,1,1) + L * (3,-1,1)$$